# Why does my curl request work and my python3 request not work when calling a webservice?

Tags: python-3.x, web-services, curl, python-requests

So I have two (what I think are) identical web service requests...one is from curl which works, and the other is in Python3.

I don't understand the difference between them because the curl one works and returns the expected result, and the Python3 one returns a 500 HTTP status code.

My `curl` call is as follows:

```
$ curl -d "{\"Service\": \"Activity\", \"Action\": \"GetDataHistory\",\"Data\": \"{'StartTime':'2019-08-20T13:00:00+00:00', 'EndTime':'2019-08-20T13:10:00+00:00','GameId':'XXXXXXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ-AAAA-BBBBBBBBBBBB'}\"}" -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "cache-control: no-cache" -H "username: someusrname" -H "password: $(echo $vlpasswd)" -X POST -k https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/Service/Call | /c/Users/meacct/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/python -m json.tool
```

And my Python3 code that "should" do the same thing is here:

```
import json
import requests as req
import urllib3

endpoint = 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/Service/Call'

h = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'cache-control': 'no-cache',
           'username': 'someusrname',
           'password':'das-passwd'
          }

d = {'Service': 'Activity', 
     'Action': 'GetDataHistory',
     'Data': 
     {
             "StartTime":"2019-08-20T13:00:00+00:00", 
             "EndTime":"2019-08-20T13:10:00+00:00",
             "GameId":"XXXXXXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ-AAAA-BBBBBBBBBBBB"
     }
}


# Shut up urllib3's warnings about an invaild SSL Certy.
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

session = req.Session()

try:
    res = session.post(url=endpoint, headers=h, data=d, verify=False)
except req.exceptions.SSLError:
    print("SSL Error")

print(res.status_code)

res.text
```

and the output is:

```
500 
'{"Message":"An error has occurred."}'
```

Why would this be when it looks to be the exact same call?

Comment: There's a tool for creating code from a curl request, have you tried that? https://github.com/NickCarneiro/curlconverter

Comment: @UnbearableLightness That sounds great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the curl request is successful, this indicates that there is something wrong in your Python request, as opposed to the server configuration.

Instead of tracking down the issue, I suggest you try using [curlconverter](https://github.com/NickCarneiro/curlconverter), to generate the Python request directly from the curl request.